# Nginx multidomain configuration on EC2 with one elastic IP

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to configure two domains on a EC2 instance sharing one elastic IP. Both domains work just fine if i assign the elastic IP in my local `/var/etc/hosts`.

I use the name servers of my registrar and put there the IP for each domain. I assume i did something wrong in the server blocks of the Nginx config.

My configuration so far looks like this:

**Domain 1:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain-1.com;
  include hhvm.conf;

  root /var/www/domain-1.com/html;
  index index.php;

  location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain-1.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }
}
```

**Domain 2:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain-2.com;
  include hhvm.conf;

  root /var/www/domain-2.com/html;
  index index.php;

  location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain-2.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Getting both just working if i browse the domain name.

Comment: And what is actually happening?

Comment: As mentioned in my initial post: assigning the IP to the domain name in my hosts file (locally) results in domains resolving properly if i open them in a browser. Without that they not resolve properly.